# STContains, STIntersects and STWithin return wrong result for geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, leaflet, sql-server-2019, geography

I'm using SQL server to store customers location info (longitude and latitude) and using leaflet to show them on map. And also I'm using leaflet for drawing polygon to draw city areas, I store polygons in a another SQL table with geography type, finally by using below query I want to know if a customer is inside an area(polygon) or not:

```
DECLARE @latitude DECIMAL(25,18);
DECLARE @longitude DECIMAL(25,18);
DECLARE @customerId BIGINT;
DECLARE @geographicalAreaId INT;
DECLARE @coordinates GEOGRAPHY;

DECLARE @isInsideArea BIT;

declare @insideCOUNT int;
SET @insideCOUNT=0;

DECLARE @point geography;
DECLARE @polygon geography;

DECLARE getCustomerGeo_CSR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY 
FOR

    SELECT DISTINCT Fk_CustomerId,ca.Latitude,ca.Longitude FROM Tbl_CustomerAddresses ca
        WHERE ca.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND ca.Longitude IS NOT NULL;

OPEN getCustomerGeo_CSR; 
FETCH NEXT
FROM getCustomerGeo_CSR
INTO @customerId,@latitude, @longitude

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @point = geography::Point(cast(@latitude as float), cast(@longitude as float), 4326);

    DECLARE getGeoArea_CSR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY 
    FOR
        SELECT ga.GeographicalAreaId,ga.Coordinates               
        FROM   Tbl_GeographicalAreas ga         
    
    OPEN getGeoArea_CSR; 
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM getGeoArea_CSR
    INTO @geographicalAreaId, @coordinates

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        
        SET @polygon = geography::STGeomFromText((SELECT Coordinates FROM Tbl_GeographicalAreas WHERE GeographicalAreaId = @geographicalAreaId).STAsText(),4326);


        IF @polygon.STContains(@point) = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @insideCOUNT = @insideCOUNT+1;
        END
        
         FETCH NEXT
         FROM getGeoArea_CSR
         INTO @geographicalAreaId, @coordinates
    END
    CLOSE getGeoArea_CSR;
    DEALLOCATE getGeoArea_CSR;
    

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM getCustomerGeo_CSR
    INTO @customerId,@latitude, @longitude
END
CLOSE getCustomerGeo_CSR;
DEALLOCATE getCustomerGeo_CSR;

print @insideCOUNT;
```

but I always get wrong value....

here is one of my polygons:

```
POLYGON ((46.389019 38.033642, 46.388397 38.029045, 46.386788 38.027253, 46.383269 38.024701, 46.37872 38.021252, 46.375308 38.020238, 46.374493 38.021861, 46.375351 38.023179, 46.37445 38.02487, 46.37327 38.025478, 46.371167 38.026543, 46.368678 38.026205, 46.367347 38.02727, 46.364343 38.028318, 46.367648 38.030076, 46.368442 38.030329, 46.3696 38.030329, 46.370029 38.030769, 46.370716 38.032036, 46.371725 38.034014, 46.372476 38.035298, 46.372626 38.035772, 46.372755 38.036819, 46.372819 38.037749, 46.373119 38.038814, 46.373441 38.039219, 46.376252 38.03785, 46.378098 38.037259, 46.380415 38.036853, 46.384835 38.036025, 46.386852 38.035079, 46.387968 38.034301, 46.388805 38.033946, 46.389019 38.033642, 46.389019 38.033642))
```

Comment: Do you have some polygon samples one can test with? Otherwise it's hard. Also, what do you mean with "wrong" value. Finally, you don't really need cursors to do what you're doing

Comment: I edited my question and added a polygon sample

Comment: can you add a customer coord you expect to be inside the polygon

Comment: Why does this need even one cursor, let alone two?

Comment: lat: 38.029599000000000000 lng:46.371402000000000000

Comment: it returns more points than actually inside my areas....

Comment: i'm suspecting your polygon might be inverted wrongly. there was another question related to this the other day

Comment: I tested ReorientObject, with no success

Comment: Looks like you have a full globe: the area is 510 million km2. https://dbfiddle.uk/kysE-8EN and see https://dbfiddle.uk/-K95pxdK so `ReorientObject` does work in this particular case. I think your polygon is going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Do you have access to SSMS? Have a look at what's displayed on the Spatial Results tab when you insert your polygon data into `SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('...', 4326);` and `SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('...', 4326).ReorientObject();`

Comment: @Charlieface you are right, so why SQL shows me it is a valid polygon?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning SSMS displays nothing...

Comment: Spatial data has orientation. For the sample polygon data included in the question the first statement will show the entire spatial view in color because the data defines a clockwise polygon. The second statement reorients the polygon to be counter-clockwise and displays only the desired region in color. This not only affects presentation but also the outcomes of contains, intersects and within.

Comment: So I think I have polygons of both type, and this is confusing how to query them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your polygons (eg the example you showed) are oriented wrong. They are still *valid*, just the interior and exterior are flipped. You can check their area and if they are too large then reorient them.

You definitely don't need cursors here. You can use `CROSS APPLY` to make intermediate calculations.

```sql
SELECT
  insideCOUNT = COUNT(*)

FROM Tbl_CustomerAddresses ca
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT point =
      geography::Point(CAST(ca.latitude AS float), CAST(ca.longitude as float), 4326)
) v1

JOIN (
    Tbl_GeographicalAreas ga
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT polygon =
          IIF(
            ga.Coordinates.STArea() > 255036000000000,
            ga.Coordinates.ReorientObject(),
            ga.Coordinates
          )
    ) v2
  )
  ON v2.polygon.STContains(v1.point) = 1

WHERE ca.Latitude IS NOT NULL
  AND ca.Longitude IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I used cursor because I need insert operation in each iteration. I will check your solution  ASAP. thanks

Comment: So why can't you just do one big insert? `INSERT... SELECT ...`

Comment: Honestly, it didn't cross my mind. But it's a good idea.

Comment: your solution did the job, just this line: ON v2.polygon.STContains(v1.point) should be ON v2.polygon.STContains(v1.point) = 1 and Reorient should be ReorientObject

Comment: would you please take a look at the SQL chat room? I asked a question there. thanks